# How to select row for an equal and different condition in qliksense

Tags: qliksense, set-analysis

my aim is just to have a set analysis in qlik sense;  I did this :

```
Sum({<[EstUnTotal_fg?] = {'NON'}, Direction <> {TOTAL}>}[CA par année])
```

My aim is to have row where

```
EstUnTotal_fg ="NON"  and Direction <> TOTAL for the CA par année
```

But the sign `<>` doesn't work. If I replace it per the sign `=` so it works.

How can I use the sign `<>` in my set analysis for my `CA par année`

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, instead of using `<>` you can use `= -`.
It is explained in [this](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Design-Blog/Excluding-values-in-Set-Analysis/ba-p/1471704) post by Henric_CronströM.
So, your set analysis would look like this:

```
Sum({<[EstUnTotal_fg?] = {'NON'}, Direcations = - {Total}>} [Ca par année})
```

I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the first response, I have found the following PDF document to be helpful:
[Set-Analysis-syntaxes-examples](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Documents/Set-Analysis-syntaxes-examples/ta-p/1491810?attachment-id=89393)

I believe there is a French (original?) version here:
[Sets-Analysis-syntaxes-exemples](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Groupe-des-Utilisateurs-Francophones/Sets-Analysis-syntaxes-exemples/td-p/1492392?attachment-id=147130)

Pay attention to page 8 (English version) where the author (also) distinguishes -= and = -.

These were sourced from the Qlik Community: [Qlik Community](https://community.qlik.com/)